# get extra column with eloquent hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have three tables cart , cart_products , products

i have that relation in cart table

```
  public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class,CartProducts::class,'cart_id','id' )->withPivot('cart_products');
    }
```

and this is my cart_products table

```
Schema::create('cart_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('product_id')
            ->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('cart_id')
            ->references('id')->on('carts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

i got all products finally , but i need to get quantity column with that realtion

any help?

Comment: You're using the wrong relation, Use `belongToMany` instead and add the `withPivot('quantity')` to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the many to many relation with `belongsToMany()`

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve the `quantity` column from the `cart_products` pivot table by passing the column name to the withPivot method

```
    //...
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
    ->using('App\CartProducts')
    ->withPivot('quantity');
```

See

> Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models

in [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)